# Konva-React Rotation Displaying

Tags: reactjs, konvajs, react-konva, konvajs-reactjs

is there a simple method to get Konva arrow object's rotation attribute after I draw an arrow with coordinates of points?

I could get with trigonometry but I wonder is there a custom way in Konva to get rotation info?

```
         <Arrow
            points={[startPos.xe, startPos.ye, endPos.xe, endPos.ye]}
            pointerLength={12}
            pointerWidth={10}
            fill='teal'
            stroke="black"
            strokeWidth={5}
            
         />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Konva doesn't have any methods for that. Also, please keep in mind that any `Konva.Node` instance has its own `rotation` attribute. So in that case, an arrow shape has `rotation = 0` (defualt value).

But you can calculate angle of arrow line for different purposes. You can use this for calculations:

```js
const getAngle = (points) => {
  const dx = points[1].x - points[0].x;
  const dy = points[1].y - points[0].y;
  const angle = Math.atan2(dy, dx);
  return Konva.Util.radToDeg(angle);
}
```